# Python: Вызов super().__init__() в метаклассах

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы, метапрограммирование

Я столкнулся с проблемой: я не очень понимаю, зачем нужно вызывать super().__init() в метаклассе. Так как, по определению метакласс это фабрика классов, зачем нужно вызывать конструктор экземпляра (Ведь в **init** мы даже не передаем имя класса, а просто аргументы)? Ведь это не очень логично. Мой IDE говорит, что я должен написать этот вызов, но без него все работает. Не могли ли бы Вы, помочь мне? Заранее спасибо! (Мой код ниже, вызов конструктора **init** закомментирован.)

```
from collections import OrderedDict
class Descriptor:
    _counter = 0

    def __init__(self):
        self.attr_name = f'{Descriptor._counter}'
        Descriptor._counter += 1

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return self if instance is None else instance.__dict__[self.attr_name]

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if value > 0:
            instance.__dict__[self.attr_name] = value
        else:
            msg = 'Value must be > 0!'
            raise AttributeError(msg)


class Meta(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, attr_dict):
        #super().__init__(name, bases, attr_dict) <-
        for key, value in attr_dict.items():
            if isinstance(value, Descriptor):
                value.attr_name = key

    @classmethod
    def __prepare__(metacls, name, bases):
        return OrderedDict()


class Shop(metaclass=Meta):
    weight = Descriptor()
    price = Descriptor()

    def __init__(self, name, price, weight):
        self.name = name
        self.price = price
        self.weight = weight

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.name}: price - {self.price} weight - {self.weight}'

    def buy(self):
        return self.price * self.weight
```

Comment: `__init__()` нужны вызывать чтобы не потерять логику предка инита. Предположим у `type` есть свой инит и он делает какую-то логику, чтобы эта логика сохранилась, нужно вызвать инит. И метакласс у вас лишний, посмотрите в сторону `__set_name__` метода у дескрипторов

Comment: Meta здесь нужен! Чтобы мне не приходилось передавать аргументы в конструктор класса дескриптора, я написал метакласс, который на этапе создания, меняет имя аргумента в дескрипторе. (Так как мы не имеем представление об имени экземпляра дескриптора на этапе создания).

Comment: Я уже сказал про метод `__set_name__`, в этот метод в момент создания экземпляра дескриптора передается имя атрибута.

Comment: То есть, в момент создания `price = Descriptor()`, в `__set_name__` передается имя  `price`. Затем уже можно `self.attr_name = name`

Comment: Это невозможно. В начале, выполняется выражение в правой части присваивания. Дескриптор понятия не имеет о том, что находится слева

Comment: Алло, как мне еще разжевать что я выше написал? Может ты наконец попробуешь открыть документацию для `__set_name__`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С точки зрения питона, `Meta` это в первую очередь класс. А это значит, что когда вызывается его конструктор и создается экземпляр класса, то нужно вызвать конструктор предка, чтобы предок сделал необходимую инициализацию.

Именно поэтому IDE показывает, что здесь вызов нужен.

Другое дело, что `type.__init__` очевидно делает что-то не слишком существенное (вообще или для сценария который тестируете), поэтому, даже если вызов пропустить, то работает. Не нужно забывать, что часть логики создания еще есть и в `__new__`. Если и его переопределить и не вызвать `__new__` у предка, то тогда все, что делает `type`, а именно создание собственно класса, сломается.

В общем случае предком вашего класса может быть любой другой класс и его `__init__` может содержать очень существенную инициализацию и ее пропускать нельзя. Хорошим тоном является вызов `__init__` у предка, даже если он (сейчас) ничего не делает. Это делает код лучше поддерживаемым. Представьте, что вы переходите на новую версию питона, а там `type.__init__` стал делать что-то важное - класс сломается.

То что класс `Meta` дополнительно используется еще как и метакласс класса `Shop` никак с этим не связанно.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Но Meta здесь нужен! Чтобы мне не приходилось передавать аргументы в конструктор класса дескриптора, я написал метакласс, который на этапе создания, меняет имя аргумента в дескрипторе. (Так как мы не имеем представление об имени экземпляра дескриптора на этапе создания). Но, возможно я Вас неправильно понял.